# Battery Percentage is not working after flashing Xperia E Dual with Nexboost ROM

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, custom-roms

I have flashed my Xperia E Dual with [Nexboost ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-j-e/development/rom-nexboost-cm11-camera-t2852519). After flashing my mobile below functionalities (a far I have identified till now) are not working:

1. Battery Percentage Status Bar (Always showing 100%)
2. FM Radio (Not installed)
3. Live Wallpaper (Not Supported)
4. Gallery (Some options are force closing this Gallery app)

Are there any solution to fix these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have read about the bugs listed on that [page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-j-e/development/rom-nexboost-cm11-camera-t2852519) before flashing the ROM. The bugs listed are -

- Battery percentage is weird at times (goes up and down). Battery life is ok, though. There seems to be a problem with the Poseidon Kernel causing this. Hope @UltraGamerHD will fix it sometime in the future.
- A lot of people ask about the stock Xperia Themes. Well, they don't work. I already changed .pngs files in various apks causing the themes to no longer work.
- Some apps force closes at times (Whatsapps, Gmail, Browser,etc..). Clearing the apps data, they'll work again.

*They did not mention anything about FM Radio.*

**So the main point is you should wait until they release their next ROM (or) flash another ROM better than this.**

Comment: Could you please suggest any better rom for xperia e dusl with less bugs and can fix above points?

Comment: Sorry @chanchal1987, I don't know much about these customized ROMs. But I hear a lot about CyanogenMod recently, because it is more actively developed than others. Check if its available for you device but remember **NO CUSTOMIZED ROM IS PERFECT**.